# AWS boto3 : ClientError when calling run_instances with AMI ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2_resource.create_instances(ImageId=MEGATRON_SCRAPER_AMI_ID, MinCount=1, MaxCount=2)
```

This throws a `ClientError` as below -

```
ClientError: An error occurred (Unsupported) when calling the 
RunInstances operation: The requested configuration is currently not 
supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
```

Concerned AWS Region is Mumbai

Comment: MEGATRON_SCRAPER? No wonder it's not working =)

Comment: @SergeyKovalev that is just a constant I am using...it has a value already defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the [EC2 Boto3 Documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migrationec2.html#launching-new-instances) is not either updated or has some other caveat attached.

Well, [the documentation here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) is pretty comprehensive and it turns out that I was actually missing an `InstanceType` argument while calling `create_instances`

So the ideal way would be:

```
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2_resource.create_instances(ImageId=MEGATRON_SCRAPER_AMI_ID, MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, InstanceType='t2.micro')
```

Also, before doing this, see if the `credentials` and `config` files in `~/.aws/` have proper values of secret keys, default region etc.